# How to avoid fixed footer overlapping?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a fixed footer at bottom, When i turn on developer options it overlaps my content div. Also, When i open this in tab it overlaps and causes problem to insert information in the form.

The way to avoid this could be z-index. But, Is there anyway to avoid it altogether?

See this image:

[image]

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add `padding-bottom` to your body, the value of `padding-bottom` should equal with the height of the footer.